# how to print decoded json correctly in php having unknown key

Tags: php, laravel

have a `json` stored in  **database** having unknown `keys`.

**i want to print them like this**

`array_key :  amount`  for first array **key => cigratte_flake, Amount => 2997**

**here is my decoded json**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cigratte_flake] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Price] => 999
                    [Quantity] => 3
                    [Amount] => 2997
                )

        )

    [wrestling_board] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Price] => 400
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [Amount] => 800
                )

        )

    [flex_board_naga_dhaga] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Price] => 300
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [Amount] => 600
                )

        )

    [total] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Price] => 
                    [Quantity] => 
                    [Amount] => 4397
                )

        )

)
```

**here is my original json:**

> {"cigratte_flake":[{"Price":"999","Quantity":"3","Amount":"2997"}],"wrestling_board":[{"Price":"400","Quantity":"2","Amount":"800"}],"flex_board_naga_dhaga":[{"Price":"300","Quantity":"2","Amount":"600"}],"total":[{"Price":null,"Quantity":null,"Amount":"4397"}]}

i know this below code, but don't know how to apply in foreach loop, other solution is most **appreciated**

```
  reset($a);
  $first_key = key($a);
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please provide your current PHP code that decodes and interpretes the JSON, so we can see where you are stuck :-)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer, `array key` will be unknown but its `values` will be `Price,Quantity,Price`

Comment: this my code  

`$d = \DB::select('SELECT sqd.quotation_data,pi.* FROM sent_quotation_data sqd
             INNER JOIN performa_invoice pi on sqd.customer_id = pi.customer_id');
       $d = collect($d);
       $j = json_decode($d[0]->quotation_data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this works with your data:

```
array_combine(array_keys($array), array_flatten(array_pluck($array, '*.Amount')))
```

Another approach is to use `mapWithKeys()` collection method:

```
collect($array)->mapWithKeys(function($i, $k) { return [$k => $i[0]['Amount']]; })
```

Comment: where would i collect `result`

Comment: how would i go to include `price` and `quantity` similar to **`Amount as here  array_pluck($array, '*.Amount')`**

Comment: @EaB how exactly do you want to include other fields? Do you want to get concatenated string like `$2997 / 3 / 999` or something?

Comment: Not like that i wanted to have a `html` `table` as  `key  :  price : quantity : amount`

Comment: @EaB to display the data, you do not need to modify it. Just iterate over it with `@foreach ($array as $key => $item) {{ $key }} : {{ $item[0]['price'] }}  @endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for this:

```
foreach ( $my_array as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key . ': ' . $value['Amount'];
}
```